# ffmpeg converting larger webm video into smaller version - loss of quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm creating a WebM formatted video in 1920x1080 using `Filmora 9` (desktop software). This works perfectly. Rather than having to re-create all my videos in smaller versions (1280x720), I'm trying to write a simple shell script that will run some comments to make smaller versions:

```
ffmpeg -i round-en-1920x1080.webm -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 0.33M -c:a libopus -b:a 96k -filter:v scale=1280:720 round-en-1280x720.webm
```

For some reason, it comes out really bad quality. Even the filesize made me question it (the original was 22mb, and the outputted was 3mb!). Am I missing some flags?

The output settings from my software look fine:

[image]

[image]

When I compare the video properties in Windows Explorer, they both have the same FPS etc, and have the correct dimensions set. I'm not sure what else could be the issue?

Here is how the same dimensions come out of my PC software:

[image]

...and then after I've run the ffmpeg command to convert the larger video into this size, this is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, there is a noticeable difference in quality :(

Comment: `0.33M` is a very low bitrate for a 720p video - workable for maybe simple slideshows. Switch to CRF mode. Start with `-crf 30 -b:v 0`. Reduce crf till it looks ok.

Comment: @Gyan thanks - that did the trick :) I was just using a command I found online to be fair - thus the 0.33mb =) This seems to do the trick now: `ffmpeg -y -i round-en-1920x1080.webm -crf 30 -b:v 0 -b:a 192k -s 1280:720 round-en-1280x720.webm`